# Adding 1 day / 24 hours to different unixtimestamp in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I add 24 hours (or 1 day) to about 20k different unixtimestamps, stored in my MySQL database?

Example, I have this:

```
expire_time = unixtimestamp
```

What would the query look like, if I was to ADD 24 hours (or 1 day) to the timestamps in the `expire_time` column?

`UPDATE table SET expire_time=expire_time+1day`

Comment: Do you mean 24 hours or 1 day.... there's a difference across to switch to/from daylight savings

Comment: @MarkBaker 24 hours will do the trick

Comment: If you just want to add 24 hours to a unix timestamp, it's `UPDATE table SET expire_time=expire_time+86400` because there are 86400 seconds in 24 hours and a unix timestamp is simply a count of the number of seconds since a base date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

I took a minute to read up on unix timestamp. and found out it is basically numbers of seconds. So what you probably will have to do is add 24 hours worth of seconds to the existing number in your database:

```
UPDATE table SET expire_time = expire_time+86400
```

This will add 86400 to the existing value, which is the same as 24 hours.

Comment: Consider yourself knocked for the first suggestion xD... I'd get rid of it because it's on a unix timestamp and not a date

Comment: Indeed. Just finished testing it myself :)